# Can someone interpret the author's explanation of linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra

The book I am reading gives this example for linear independence of vectors.  I do not understand how he got the three equations below, such as B1 - B3 = 0.
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That starting equation means $$\beta_1\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right] + \beta_2 \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] + \beta_3\left[\begin{array}{c}-1 \\ 1\\ 1 \end{array}\right]= 0$$ Can you simplify the left-hand-side?

Comment: ...and in this context $0$ means $\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Well I if I multiply it through, there still would be 3 vectors.  I know the definition of linear independence is that Bs are equal to 0.  I just don't understand his point.

Comment: What do you get when you multiply through?

Comment: @confused The three equations are the equations that say that the x-coordinate of the linar combination is zero, that the y-coordinate is zero, and that the z-coordinate is zero.

Comment: So then you agree this reduces to $\beta_1-\beta_3=0$, $-\beta_2 + \beta_3=0$, $\beta_2+\beta_3=0$?

Comment: [B1, 0, 0] + [0, -B2, B2] + [-B3, B3, B3] = [0, 0, 0];  Oh I see, he just split the vectors into 3 equations.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  We have 3 rows and that gives three separate equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3$ being l.i. means that if $\beta_1\alpha_1 + \beta_2\alpha_2 + \beta_3\alpha_3=0$, then $\beta_1= \beta_2=\beta_3=0$. This equation gives $[\beta_1 +(-1)\beta_3, (-1)\beta_2+\beta_3, \beta_2 +\beta_3]=(0,0,0)$, from which the author derived those three equalities.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are defined to be linearly independent if and only if the only solution to the equation $\sum\lambda_iv_i = 0$ is $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=...=\lambda_n = 0$.

The author has basically demonstrated this by finding the unique solution for this